# Last working day for n Months ago SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below sql query which selects the date as of end of 3months ago. How can I alter it to select the last **working** day from three months ago?

```
(SELECT DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())-3,0)))
```

Comment: Maybe [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/94944/Get-the-last-working-day-of-the-month) could help you.

Comment: Doesn't look like mysql to me. More like sql server or something. Please tag correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MSSQL.
If for "last working day" you just mean Saturday and Sunday, you can try following query.
In MSSQL the number of day in week, depends by value of @@datefirst (you can set it with SET DATEFIRST n, where n=1, ..., 7).
Eg. if @@datefirst=7 first day of week is Sunday, so DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) will return 1 is today is Sunday.
This query try to give you "last working day" apart from @@datefirst value.

```
SELECT DATEADD(d, - CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,SP)+@@datefirst IN (7,8) THEN DATEPART(dw,SP) + @@datefirst-6  ELSE 0 END,SP) AS ND        
    FROM (
        SELECT DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(mm,
                DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())
            -3,0)) AS SP ) A
```

Output

```
2017-04-28 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to consider: May 31, 2010 occurred on a Monday that happened to be a [Federal Holiday in the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labor_Day). So, for many businesses (or business units), the last working day of that month was actually Friday, May 28, 2010.

So, here is a robust solution that can account for holidays.

First we assume that we have a [Calendar Table](https://www.google.com/search?q=calendar+table+tsql&search_plus_one=form&oq=calendar+table+tsql).

With respect to the `Calendar` table, a `Holiday` table can be defined as:

```
create table Holiday (id int primary key foreign key references Calendar)
```

and populated like so (the example is USA-centric, but can generalize to any country):

```
insert Holiday
    --Labor Day 
    select C.* from Calendar C where C.month =  5 and C.day_name = 'monday' and C.day_of_month > 25 union
    --Christmas
    select C.* from Calendar C where C.month = 12 and C.day_of_month = 25 union
    --Thanksgiving
    select C.* from Calendar C where C.month = 11 and c.day_name = 'thursday' and abs(C.day_of_month - 25) <= 3
    --etc...
```

So, for a typical business, a `WorkDay` view might be defined as:

```
create view WorkDay as
    select id from Calendar where day_name not in ('saturday', 'sunday') 
        except select id from Holiday
```

Hence, our final query is simply:

```
with Q as (select top 1 * from Calendar C where datediff(month, C.date, getdate()) = 3),

P as
(
    select C.* from Calendar C
        cross apply ( select * from Q where C.year = Q.year and C.month = Q.month) L        
)

select top 1 * from P inner join WorkDay W on W.id = P.id order by P.id desc
```

**Q** gets a date that occurred in whatever month it was three months ago.

**P** gets all of the days that occurred in the same month of the date returned by **Q**.

Finally, the last query returns the last day of the month returned by **P** that was a work day, where "work day" means not a **Saturday** or **Sunday** and not a holiday.

In this example, the Calendar table is defined as:

```
create table Calendar
(
    id int primary key identity,
    date datetime unique not null,
    day_of_week as datepart(dw, date),
    month as datepart(month, date),
    day_name as datename(dw, date),
    year as datepart(year, date),
    day_of_month as datepart(day, date),
    week as datepart(week, date)
)
```